# Getting a data attributes value from a div one step above

Tags: jquery

In the following scenario, how do i get the value of `data-kush` when I click on the readMore link?

There are more products displayed the same way, and I need to display the value of the data-kush that is above the readMore link that is clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/fge72ma9/

```
<div>
<div class="product itemName" data-kush="9a7e96cb9b72fb8c526961e7366bf1a8">
    Norwegian Kush
</div>

<div class="moreInfo">
    <span class="readMore">Click to read more...</span>
</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="product itemName" data-kush="fb8c526961e7366bf1a8">
    Bubba Kush
</div>

<div class="moreInfo">
    <span class="readMore">Click to read more...</span>
</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.readMore').click(function() {
    alert($(this).closest('.itemName').data('kush'));
});
```

The above is what I thought would work, but does not. Can you help?

Comment: `$(this).parent().prev('.itemName').data('kush')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is the previous sibling of current element's parent.

So

```js
$('.readMore').click(function() {
  alert($(this).parent().prev('.itemName').data('kush'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="product itemName" data-kush="9a7e96cb9b72fb8c526961e7366bf1a8">
    Norwegian Kush
  </div>

  <div class="moreInfo">
    <span class="readMore">Click to read more...</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div class="product itemName" data-kush="fb8c526961e7366bf1a8">
    Bubba Kush
  </div>

  <div class="moreInfo">
    <span class="readMore">Click to read more...</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) is used for getting an ancestor element, here since the target element is not an ancestor it won't work

Answer (score 0):

> For each element in the set , **.closest()** get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

In your Question , you did this

```
 $(this).closest('.itemName')
```

as `.itemName` is not the `ancestor` of `.readMore` nor it matches with the selector `.readMore`

For more you can check [API](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

This will provide you an `Exception`. So you need to `access` the right element by doing like this

```
 $('.readMore').click(function () {
      alert($(this).closest('div').siblings('.itemName').attr('data-kush'));
 });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fge72ma9/2/)